# The location parameter is not a valid S3 uri - AWS::Include Location does not accept local path but S3 location

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

When I try to provide the relative path of MyFileName.yaml as follows in my cloudformation template, I get the error - **Transform AWS::Include failed with: The location parameter is not a valid S3 uri**

```
Fn::Transform:
  Name: AWS::Include
  Parameters:
    Location: ../MyFileName.yaml
```

I fixed it by uploading **MyFileName.yaml** in an S3 bucket and updating the template as follows:

```
Location: s3://<bucket-name>/MyFileName.yaml
```

However, I would like to know if it allows only S3 location and not local path. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Location` parameter can *only* be an S3 location.

Based on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html):

> We currently support Amazon S3 URI, but no other Amazon S3 format (such as Amazon S3 ARN). It must be an Amazon S3 bucket, as opposed to something like a GitHub repository.

I'd recommend adding a step to your CI/CD pipeline for uploading the templates to S3 to automate this process